# Why isn't it printing properly?

Tags: c++, increment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int vCorrectOrWrong(string UserAnswer, string CorrectAnswer, int k);
string vAnswerSheet(string sArray[], string sUserAnswer, int iElement);
void vResults(int,int);

int main()
{
const int ctSIZE = 5;
string sQuestions[ctSIZE] = {"1. What was the first planet to be discovered by the telescope?", "2. What is the diameter of earth?",
                             "3. Name the yellow teletubby?", "4. In which state was the first oil well drilled in the Untied States?", "5. How many tentacles does a squid have?" };
string sLetterAnwers[ctSIZE] = {"a. Mars b. Mercury c. Uranus d. Jupiter", "a. 5,000 miles b. 6,000 miles c. 7,000 miles d. 8,000 miles",
                                "a. Dipsy b. Po c. LaLa d. Tinky Winky", "a. Pennsylvania b. Texas c. Wyoming d. North Dakota", "a. 8 b. 9 c. 10 d. 11"};
string sUserAnswer;
string a;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k =0;

while(i != 5)
{
cout << sQuestions[i] << endl;
cout << sLetterAnwers[i] << endl;
cin >> sUserAnswer;

a = vAnswerSheet(sLetterAnwers,sUserAnswer,i);
j = vCorrectOrWrong(sUserAnswer, a,k);
i++;
}
vResults(j,ctSIZE);
cout << "PROGRAM ENDED!" << endl;
return 0;
}

string vAnswerSheet(string sArray[], string sUserAnswer, int i)
{
string x = sArray[i];
string Answer;
if(sArray[0] == x)
    Answer = "c";
    else if(sArray[1] == x)
        Answer = "d";
    else if(sArray[2] == x)
        Answer = "c";
    else if (sArray[3] == x)
        Answer = "a";
    else if (sArray[4] == x)
        Answer = "c";

return Answer;
}
```

**why wont k increment** Thanks in advance! I apologize if the code looks sloppy very new to the coding world.

```
 int vCorrectOrWrong(string UserAnswer,string CorrectAnswer, int k)
 {
 if( UserAnswer != CorrectAnswer )
     cout << "WRONG!" << endl;
     else
     {
         cout <<"RIGHT!"<< endl;
         k++;
     }
    return k;
  }
```

////////////////////////////////

```
 void vResults(int y, int x)
 {
     cout << " You got: " << y << " of the " << x << " Questions correct!"<<       endl;
     y = y*100/x;
     cout <<y<<"%"<< endl;
 }
```

Comment: I suggest you read about passing parameters by value vs by reference in your favorite C++ textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value k by reference to vResults that way you don't have to return the same value into j and use it. Like this -

Your function vCorrectOrWrong will look like -

```
int vCorrectOrWrong(string UserAnswer, string CorrectAnswer, int &k) {..}
```

And instead of calling it as -

```
j = vCorrectOrWrong(sUserAnswer, a,k);
..
..
vResults(j,ctSIZE);
```

call it like this -

```
vCorrectOrWrong(sUserAnswer, a,k);
..
..
vResults(k,ctSIZE);
```

Comment: Hey linuxmonk! I appreciate the quick reply! Your code did the job works like a charm.Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep better track of your variables.

Inside of your `while (i != 5)` loop you keep setting `j` to whatever the output of `vCorrectOrWrong` is.  The problem is you always use `k` as a parameter to `vCorrectOrWrong` and **`k` is always equal to 0** when it is used as a parameter.  The `j` at the end you use in your output will be either 0 if the user gets the last question wrong, or 1 if the user gets the last question right.

I highly recommend using a debugger or inserting `cout` statements in your code to help you keep track of what values are stored in the variables.  I'll leave fixing this problem up to you.